# Using a Chinese iPhone XR On Verizon Wireless

Tags: iphone, compatibility

I am currently in China until February and would like to purchase a new phone.  If I purchase an iPhone XR here, would I run into any trouble running it on Verizon Wireless once I am back in the states?  In addition to general compatibility, would there be any performance issues on Verizon's network?

From what I can tell, the only difference between the Chinese version and the American version is the physical twin SIM inputs on the Chinese phone and the lack of a specific radio band.  Are there any other discerning differences between the two?

Comment: all iPhone XR have same hardware. You can travel for America to China and it still works.  Once back in States just go to Verizon and get they SIM card.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209044